# How to retrieve data from database with autocomplete (Django)

Tags: python, django

I need to get data from database and put it on input field but I can't do it.

This is my code.

template.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "/autocomplete/",
            minLength: 2,
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

urls.py

```
path('autocomplete', views.autocomplete, name='autocomplete'),
```

views.py

```
def autocomplete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.GET
    product = data.get("term")
    if product:
        products = Product.objects.filter(product_name__icontains=product)
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()

    results = []

    for pd in products:
        pd_json = {}
        pd_json['id'] = pd.id
        pd_json['label'] = pd.product_name
        pd_json['value'] = pd.product_name
        results.append(pd_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Or maybe because I didn't import something? (such as something about 'json')

Answer (score 0):

In another way, if I use this method, how can I get data from database to list of 'availableTags' ?

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
</script>
```